# How to change images in a chrome extension dynamically?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension and I want it to change images everyday. How is it possible after I've published the extension? as in, do I have to update it with different images everytime?

Comment: I'd use an online image repository like flickr or some wallpaper site, [Google Art Project](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-art-project/akimgimeeoiognljlfchpbkpfbmeapkh) extension does something of the kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to host the image somewhere the extension can access. Preferably with CORS enabled, or you'll potentially run into issues.

It's important to only request it once and then somehow save it on your side (for example, as a data URI that you can store in `chrome.storage`).